# How do I create multiple parameters PostgresFunctionExpression

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I have a query

```sql
select
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Order")  as median
```

How do I use this function in EF
EF.Functions or defined function mapping?

I try to define function
method:

```cs
public double Median<T>(int percentile, T data, bool asc) => throw new NotImplementedException();

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
        builder.HasDbFunction(method)
            .HasTranslation(......)
}
```

But I can't put more than one parameter in PostgresFunctionExpression

Comment: You cannot create such function. It requires free form text expression with parameters, which is not allowed by current EF Core code. You need to deep dive in Npgsql EF Core provider and improve query generation by replacing `NpgsqlQuerySqlGenerator` with extended realization.